# Connecting Droid Maxx for Android Development

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, motorola

I would like to use my Droid Maxx for Android Development.

I've enabled "USB debugging" from the developer options and have ran adb.exe with "kill-server" and "devices". Yet, the device still is not found.

Perhaps this could do with USB settings?

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the device driver for your phone for Windows (assuming you're on Windows):

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/95488/p/30,6720,8882