# Eclipse not recogniz the android device (Motorola Droid Razr Maxx hd)

Tags: android, eclipse, device, motorola-droid

I'm using the Eclipse ADT bundle on Windows 7 32-bit.
I'm trying to run my app on my phone **(Motorola Droid Razr Maxx hd)** which is running android 4.4.2 kitkat. I Have turned on USB debugging on the phone, and have installed drivers. But the eclipse doesn't show my device. here is the 
[image: screenshot]

My Apps min sdk:8 and Target sdk:19

I know there are similar questions

- [Device not being detected in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847508/device-not-being-detected-in-eclipse)
- [Connecting Droid Maxx for Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762694/connecting-droid-maxx-for-android-development)
- [Eclipse cannot find my android 4.1.2 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863416/eclipse-cannot-find-my-android-4-1-2-device)
- [Why is Eclipse's Android Device Chooser not showing my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device?rq=1)

but these doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Does running `adb devices` in a command prompt show the device?

Comment: @ipavl No there is no device.check [this](http://imgur.com/hHLyuX1)

Comment: I did, but I suppose that would probably show the same as `adb devices`. Make sure Windows is detecting your phone, as if it isn't then your problem isn't adb/Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if your phone adb device is detected and visible in windows devices manager. Possible reasons are:
Turned off USB debugging.
Not installed drivers for this specific phone model (as far as I remember, old motorola devices works with drivers from Motorola, not the Google's one.
Check connection - I had some troubles when connected phone with some low quality USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your Device Manager (on windows 7 click Start, right-click Computer and choose Manage) you might see that Motorola ADB Interface doesn't have a driver.  This is what happened to me after my phone's Android operating system upgraded from 4.x to 5.1.

The driver can be found inside the Motorola Device Manager on Motorola's website.  [This will get you the drivers for Windows](http://www.motorola.com/getmdmwin) and [this will get the drivers for Mac](http://www.motorola.com/getmdmmac).

After I installed the latest driver adb could find my devices again (verified by running `adb devices` on the command line)